# How to identify the repeating unit in a polymer?

Tags: homework, polymers

> Polyvinyl acetate, PVA, is a useful adhesive for gluing together articles made from wood, paper or cardboard. The monomer of PVA is ethenyl ethanoate.
>    PVA is formed from B by the process of addition polymerisation.
>   Draw a section of the PVA molecule containing at least 2 monomer molecules and identify clearly the repeating unit.
>   ([Source](http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Chemistry%20%289701%29/9701_s11_qp_42.pdf): University of Cambridge international Examinations, General Certificate of Education Advanced Level, Chemistry, Paper 4 Structured Questions, May/June 2011, Q4)

Shouldn't the $\ce{C=C}$ double bond break and each of the carbon atoms involved in the double bond are attached to $\ce{CH3OCO}$. so the repeating unit is $\ce{CH3OCO}$.

Comment: Elements of backbone also repeat.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that the "double bond breaks," it's that the vinyl C=C bond reacts during the radical addition polymerization to create [polyvinyl acetate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_acetate).

I'd disagree that the repeat unit is $\ce{CH3OCO}$ since that ignores the backbone entirely. Instead, if you look at the Wikipedia article (or any other picture of polyvinyl acetate), I'd call the repeat unit something like $\ce{-(CH2CH(OC=OCH3)-)}$ or something like that.